# Sprinkler system in indoor arena

Tags: water, irrigation

I have an indoor arena equipped with 14 water lines & stations for watering the indoor arena floor to keep dust down.
The water lines are 1 inch black pipe.  There are 6 sprinklers per truss.  Each water line runs off separate stations that are programmed to run at various intervals.  The span is 72 feet and each line has drain valves for blowing them out when winter comes.
The sprinklers are 1/2 male threaded impulse sprinklers that are hanging down 1 ft from lines.  I know these things are not really designed to run upside down but they do a really decent job of covering the arena floor evenly.
The problem is as each station shuts off the 72 feet of line drains out each sprinkler head until the line is empty.  This leaves puddles of water that can be problematic with footing for the horses.
Does anyone know of a valve that I could install on each drop that would shut off without electricity to prevent this draining action from occurring?

Comment: How high above the arena floor are the sprinkler head?

Comment: -1 Because the question is not about home improvement and I can't think of an application to home improvement where this valve would be useful. This question should probably be closed.

Comment: @BMitch this application may not be exactly on-topic, but this is a common problem in greenhouses.

Comment: @longneck in that case, perhaps it's a candidate for migrating to G&L?

Comment: @BMitch maybe, but DIY'r green thumbs might come here, too.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about industrial, commercial or agricultural applications, not Home Improvement.

Answer (score 3):

Are the sprinkler heads attached to the underside of the supply line? The proper way to design this system would be to have the sprinkler attach to the top of the supply line instead of the bottom.

[image]

With the sprinkler heads attached above the supply line, the most excess water that would be drained is the water in the short pipe above the sprinkler head.